# How do I change viewControllers in swift with Foundation Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to programmatically switch to another viewController scene when a certain event happens in Xcode for a MacOS app but am having trouble.
The second view controller is in the same storyboard as the one I am trying to switch from.
I currently have

```
let secondViewController = ViewController(nibName: "outcome", bundle: nil)
            self.present(secondViewController, animator: true as! NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator)
```

but it seems to crash when the event is triggered:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Bool' (0x2010043a8) to '__C.NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator' (0x2007787d0).
```

it also shows an error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` on the second command where I `self.present`

Comment: Check the syntax of the present method. you definitely don't want an 'as!' in there.

Comment: `true` isn't an animator. See [present(_:animator:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434431-present). The animator should be a [NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontrollerpresentationanimator). "You might find what you need in the NSViewController.TransitionOptions enumeration, which provides many predefined animations."

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to cast a `bool` to `NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator`

try this code instead:

```
let secondViewController = ViewController(nibName: "outcome", bundle: nil)
 self.present(secondViewController, animator: true)
```

Comment: Build error: "Argument type 'Bool' does not conform to expected type 'NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator'" "Insert ' as! NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator'"

Comment: You need to create a ```NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator``` tu put in there as parameter

Comment: Edit your code please.